# Reading partitioned Parquet file with Pyarrow uses too much memory

Tags: pandas, hdfs, parquet, impala, pyarrow

I have a large Impala database composed of partitioned Parquet files.
I copied one Parquet partition to the local disk using HDFS directly. This partition has 15GB total and is composed of lots of files with 10MB each. I'm trying to read this using Pandas with the Pyarrow engine or Pyarrow directly, but its size in memory uses more than 60GB of RAM and it doesn't read the entire dataset before using all memory. What could be the reason of such large memory usage?

Comment: Is 15GB the total size of the files?

Comment: Yep, the size of the entire partition that I copied, that of course has many fines.

Answer (score 2):

The size of Parquet files on disk and in memory can vary up to a magnitude. Parquet using efficient encoding and compression techniques to store columns. When you load this data into RAM, the data is unpacked into its uncompressed form. Thus for a data set of files with a size of 15G, a RAM usage of 150G would be expected.

When you're unsure if this is your problem, load a single file using `df = pandas.read_parquet` and inspect its memory usage with `df.memory_usage(deep=True)`. This should give you a good indication of the scaling between disk and RAM of your whole dataset.